# Express JS how to redirect all http traffic to https (Heroku)

Tags: reactjs, express, heroku

I want a mechanism in my Express JS app to redirect all http traffic to https traffic, similar to Rails's force_ssl config. (In Rails's case, it simply sends back a Redirect response to the client

I think the Express server code would go in Server.js, but I need to distinguish these requests from secure (https) requests that should go to the real app.

I think the redirection code looks like this:

```
var http = express.createServer();
http.get('*', function(req, res) {
  res.redirect('https://' + req.headers.host + req.url);    
})
// have it listen on 8080
http.listen(80);
```

You'll note that I can't actually listen for the port by port number, because on Heroku there's the added complication that the app may be redeployed listening on app port of their choosing (it changes every time is redeployed).

so, in essence, I need a way to detect the protocol (http or https) without using the port number here in the Express setup, and then redirect http traffic to https.

The app itself is modeled after "Create React App on Heroku" here https://originmaster.com/running-create-react-app-and-express-crae-on-heroku-c39a39fe7851, so essentially it is a REACT app being served by Express JS on Heroku.

and with example app here https://github.com/Johnnycon/crae-heroku

where I'm stuck is that i've examined the 'process' variable, and while it contains a lot of information, it does not seem to contain any request information, like the protocol or url, as the request comes in.

Any tips or suggestions?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Typically in your `server.js` near the top, add this function:

```js
// On Heroku, SSL termination happens at the load balancer,
// BEFORE encrypted traffic reaches your node app.
function enforceHttps(req, res, next) {
  // Check if directly requested via https
  if (req.secure) {
    next();
    // Heroku sets a header X-Forwarded-Proto to pass the user requested protocol
  } else if ((req.headers['x-forwarded-proto'] || '').substring(0, 5) === 'https') {
    next();
    // Only redirect GET and HEAD requests
  } else if (req.method === 'GET' || req.method === 'HEAD') {
    const host = req.headers['x-forwarded-host'] || req.headers.host;
    // redirect with 301 Moved Permanently instead of default 302
    res.redirect(301, `https://${host}${req.originalUrl}`);
  } else {
    res.status(403).send('This server requires an HTTPS connection.');
  }
}
```

and then later in the file after you define you `app`, typically as `const app = express();`:

```js
app.use(enforceHttps);
```

Comment: this works fine except important to note to put the enforceHttps function at the top of your server.js file (before you use it, of course) and also you'll want ```app.use(enforceHttps);``` to come basically right after ```const app = express();``` (I see no reason to put it later)… if  you put it too late in the file your app will pick up the request without making the desired https redriection